# How to obtain the first letter in a Bash variable?

Tags: bash, text-processing, variable-expansion

I have a Bash variable, `$word`, which is sometimes a word or sentence, e.g.:

```
word="tiger"
```

Or:

```
word="This is a sentence."
```

How can I make a new Bash variable which is equal to only the first letter found in the variable? E.g., the above would be:

```
echo $firstletter
t
```

Or:

```
echo $firstletter
T
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
initial="$(echo $word | head -c 1)"
```

Every time you say "first" in your problem description, `head` is a likely solution.

Comment: Please note that there is no `-c` option in POSIX head: <http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/head>.

Comment: This does return the first letter, but it's an overkill, and the solution depends on external utilities (head). This can be done in pure shell, which is cleaner.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, for the reasons pointed out by the above comments. The real answers are below - `${word:0:1}` or `${word::1}`.

Comment: For POSIX compliance you could do `echo "$word" | fold -w1 | head -n 1`,   `printf '%.1s' "$X"` or `printf '%c' "$X"` but these are all subject to single v. multi byte character shenanigans.

Comment: Wait, so is `head -c n`, whoops.  `echo "fábio" | head -c 2` gives `f� `, so that's another problem with this I guess.

Comment: To update the accepted answer would take a @Villiage.  Wanna?  The community would thank you ...

Comment: This is overkill if you want to get the first character(s) of a bash variable. It is a fine solution if you want the first character(s) of anything else regardless of your shell. E.g. in a script run by `sh`: `date +%N | head -c 7`.

Answer (score 353):

```
word="tiger"
firstletter=${word:0:1}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. One-liner, without spawning subshells. Take my vote !

Answer (score 92):

```
word=something
first=${word::1}
```

Comment: This would be wonderful, but does not work for me, neither in bash 4.3.11 nor in zsh 5.0.5

Comment: With GNU bash v4.3.11, `first` is set to the letter `s`. You can see it with `echo $s`. If that doesn't work for you, and you'd like help debugging, please copy and paste the command(s) you typed and their output.

Comment: Thanks Adam, my bad, I can't figure out why it didn't work for me before, but it works perfectly fine now on several version of bash I tried, going back to GNU bash, v3.1.0.
Still doesn't work in zsh, but the question is tagged "bash", so that's irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for following up and confirming! Glad it's working for you.

Comment: For zsh users: It is working with `${word:0:1}`

Answer (score 17):

A portable way to do it is to use [parameter expansion (which is a POSIX feature)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
$ word='tiger'
$ echo "${word%"${word#?}"}"
t
```

Comment: More reasonable to use are the other answers with `::` but I can't miss to upvote such an abuse of expansion. Nicely done.

Comment: It's *often* the case that you need to shell out in a scripting environment that mandates, well POSIX `sh`, not `bash` (though that was not part of the question)

Answer (score 7):

With cut :

```
word='tiger'
echo "${word}" | cut -c 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `sed` tag here is a `sed` answer:

```
echo "$word" | sed -e "{ s/^\(.\).*/\1/ ; q }"
```

Play by play for those who enjoy those (I do!):

`{`

- `s`: start a substitution routine

  - `/`: Start specifying what is to be substituted
  - `^\(.\)`: capture the first character in Group 1
  - `.*`:, make sure the rest of the line will be in the substitution
  - `/`: start specifying the replacement
  - `\1`: insert Group 1
  - `/`: The rest is discarded`;`
- `q`: Quit `sed` so it won't repeat this block for other lines if there are any.

`}`

Well that was fun! `:)` You can also use `grep` and etc but if you're in `bash` the `${x:0:1}` magick is still the better solution imo. (I spent like an hour trying to use POSIX variable expansion to do that but couldn't `:(`  )

Answer (score 1):

Using bash 4:

```
x="test"
read -N 1 var <<< "${x}"
echo "${var}"
```