# How to get first character of variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get the first character of a variable, but I'm getting a Bad substitution error.  Can anyone help me fix it?

code is:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read line
do
  if [ ! ${line:0:1} == "#"] # Error on this line
  then
    eval echo "$line"
    eval createSymlink $line
  fi
done < /some/file.txt
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way of doing this?

-- EDIT --

As requested - here's some sample input which is stored in /some/file.txt

```
$MOZ_HOME/mobile/android/chrome/content/browser.js
$MOZ_HOME/mobile/android/locales/en-US/chrome/browser.properties
$MOZ_HOME/mobile/android/components/ContentPermissionPrompt.js
```

Comment: maybe you need a space between the closing quote and the closing brackets, i.e. `"#" ]`

Comment: also you might as well go with `A != B` instead of `! A == B`

Comment: @doubleDown neither of those worked - sorry!  Still getting a Bad substitution error on that line

Comment: @Martyn can you post some input data from file.txt so we can test?

Comment: Perhaps there is a blank line in the file, or a line starting with whitespace? try with `if [ ! "${line:0:1}" == "#" ]`

Comment: can't reproduce the substitution error, even with the given sample input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain the first letter in a Bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218474/how-to-obtain-the-first-letter-in-a-bash-variable)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the first character of a variable you need to say:

```
v="hello"
$ echo "${v:0:1}"
h
```

However, your code has a syntax error:

```
[ ! ${line:0:1} == "#"]
#                     ^-- missing space
```

So this can do the trick:

```
$ a="123456"
$ [ ! "${a:0:1}" == "#" ] && echo "doesnt start with #"
doesnt start with #
$ a="#123456"
$ [ ! "${a:0:1}" == "#" ] && echo "doesnt start with #"
$
```

Also it can be done like this:

```
$ a="#123456"
$ [ "$(expr substr $a 1 1)" != "#" ] && echo "does not start with #"
$ 
$ a="123456"
$ [ "$(expr substr $a 1 1)" != "#" ] && echo "does not start with #"
does not start with #
```

#### Update

Based on your update, this works to me:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read line
do
  echo $line
  if [ ! "${line:0:1}" == "#" ] # Error on this line
  then
    eval echo "$line"
    eval createSymlink $line
  fi
done < file
```

Comment: Now I see doubleDown commented it. Will delete when he posts his answer!

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for sportsmanship too!  FYI I tried this :   a="123456" | [ ! "${a:0:1}" == "#" ] && echo "doesnt start with #" and got a BS error on that too.  Could it be something to do with bash version?

Comment: Oh I see, uhms. What about `[ "${a:0:1}" != "#" ]` ?, maybe the ` [ ! a == b ]` is not nice for your bash version.

Comment: Nice to read that, @Martyn! You can get more info about this in http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html

Comment: And if @doubleDown wants to post an answer I keep my promise of deleting mine :D With +3 votes it would even make me earn a Disciplined badge!

Comment: I'm game if @doubleDown wants to play that way :)

Comment: If the first character is `!` it does not work @fedorqui 'SO stop harming'

Answer (score 4):

Adding the missing space (as suggested in [fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17723820/1743811) ;) ) works for me.

### An alternative method/syntax

Here's what I would do in Bash if I want to check the first character of a string

```
if [[ $line != "#"* ]]
```

On the right hand side of `==`, the quoted part is treated literally whereas `*` is a wildcard for any sequence of character.

For more information, see the last part of [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) of Bash reference manual:

> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

### Checking that you're using the right shell

If you are getting errors such as "**Bad substitution error**" and "**[[: not found**" (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723790/how-to-get-first-character-of-variable/17724657#comment25835992_17724657)) even though your syntax is fine (and works fine for others), it might indicate that you are using the wrong shell (i.e. not Bash).

So to make sure you are using Bash to run the script, either

- make the script executable and use an appropriate shebang e.g. `#!/bin/bash`
- or execute it via `bash my_script`

Also note that **sh** is not necessarily **bash**, sometimes it can be **dash** (e.g. in Ubuntu) or just plain ol' Bourne shell.

Comment: Maybe... you're not even using Bash?

Comment: % echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: what do you get with `type [[`?

Comment: % type [[
[[ is a shell keyword

Comment: If you're running this code in a script, maybe try adding the shebang `#!/bin/bash` to the top of it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33705/discussion-between-martyn-and-doubledown)

Comment: I see it was a matter of the way the script was executed, well done for finding it out!

Comment: @fedorqui, Yeah. I'm just glad that this didn't end up as one of those non-reproducible mystery cases.

Comment: Good! So I'm ready to delete my answer when this answer is accepted :) If @Martyn considers it necessary, of course

Comment: @fedorqui, I don't think that's necessary. Our answers are not exactly alike.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read line
do
  if ! [ "${line:0:1}" = "#" ]; then
    eval echo "$line"
    eval createSymlink $line
  fi
done < /some/file.txt
```

or you can use the following for your `if` syntax:

```
if [[ ! ${line:0:1} == "#" ]]; then
```

Comment: +1 Also good point putting the negation condition outside the brakets. I am wondering what is the most POSIX way!

Comment: @fedorqui: '!' is a valid "not" parameter of the test ([) command, so I'd keep it inside, myself

Answer (score 0):

TIMTOWTDI ^^

```
while IFS='' read -r line
do
  case "${line}" in
    "#"*)  echo "${line}"
    ;;
    *)     createSymlink ${line}
    ;;
  esac
done  < /some/file.txt
```

Note: I dropped the eval, which could be needed in some (rare!) cases (and are dangerous usually).

Note2: I added a "safer" IFS & read (-r, raw) but you can revert to your own if it is better suited. Note that it still reads line by line.

Note3: I took the habit of using always ${var} instead of $var ... works for me (easy to find out vars in complex text, and easy to see where they begin and end at all times) but not necessary here.

Note4: you can also change the test to : `*"#"*)` if some of the (comments?) lines can have spaces or tabs before the '#' (and none of the symlink lines does contain a '#')